# How to make a Excel based VBA UserForm act on its own?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I've created a UserForm in Excel 2016 that utilizes UDF's; I'd like to be able to have the UserForm run without having the excel sheet open up and allow for other excel workbooks to be opened and manipulated at the same time that the tool is active.  Some solutions I've found say to use the following:

```
Private Sub MyForm_Initialize()
  Application.Visible = False
  UserForm1.Activate
End Sub
```

However, this leaves the Excel open in the background after the UserForm is closed, and all other active Excel sheets are hidden and cannot easily be manipulated.

Is there a way to make the UserForm essentially act as a standalone application without using VBA.net?

Comment: I'd recommend re-writing as a stand alone question and then posting an answer to your own question ([yes this is allowed on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer))

Comment: [so] is Q&A, not some discussion forum. Question field hosts questions, answer fields hold answers, and titles don't have `[SOLVED]` or `[SOLUTION]` or whatever other annoying tags in the title. Please [edit] your post so that it *looks* like a Q&A. As it stands, it's completely unclear what you're asking.

Comment: So you are using a userform from a non-visible workbook to act as the control window to do predefined functions on other workbooks?  Good Idea.

Comment: Sorry about the poor format of my post, this was my first posting here, and I thought that in my search for pieces of my solution that I saw several SO posts like that.  I've edited this post to match suggestions.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Code will go in several different places, "ThisWorkbook" object and the "UserForm" code.

"ThisWorkbook" contains code that will determine if the UserForm is the only Excel thing (workbook) open, and if it is it will hide the Excel application and hide the workbook itself. and if other workbooks are open it simply hides the workbook.  I have it set to hide the application and the workbook in both cases so that a new instance of Excel can be opened after the UserForm is running without pulling up the workbook associated with the UserForm.  The code for this is below (goes into the "ThisWorkbook" object):

```
Private Sub WorkBook_Open()
  Dim wb As Workbook
     Set wb = Workbooks("MyBook.xlsm")
    If Workbooks.Count > 1 Then 

       wb.Windows(1).Visible = False
    Else
       wb.Windows(1).Visible = False
       Application.Visible = False
    End If
   UserForm1.Show vbModeless
   'Put defaults and populations here
End Sub
```

The `UserForm1.Show vbModeless`allows for Excel to be used while the UserForm is active.
A couple of notes on this section:

- "UserForm1" is the name of my UserForm, change this to the name of yours
- Where I `Set wb = Workbooks("")` change inside the quotes to the name of the 
  workbook the UserForm is in
- The `IfElse` statement could be eliminated and moved to the `If`, if you don't need any other action on the opening with no other workbooks open

The next section of code goes in the UserForm Code. I have a button set up to show the Excel workbook in order to edit it and whatnot, you could have a region you click if you don't want a button to show up.  When you want to activate the Excel sheet and the application will need to be activated.  I unload (deactivate) the active thing (the UserForm).  This bit of code isn't necessary if the user doesn't need access to the spreadsheet:

```
Private Sub See_Excel_Click()

   Dim wb As Workbook
   Set wb = Workbooks("MyBook.xlsm")
   wb.Windows(1).Visible = True
   Application.Visible = True
   wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

   Unload Me

End Sub
```

Within the userform there should be a way to handle what happens when the userform is closed, as the excel application and workbook will stay open hidden in the background.  I have the action close the workbook and the application.  A quick note, if you set the `Cancel = True` then the red x button won't close the userform.  The code I use for this is:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

    If CloseMode = 0 Then
      Cancel = False
      Dim wb As Workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks("MyBook.xlsm")
      wb.Windows(1).Visible = True
      Application.Visible = True
      ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
      ThisWorkbook.Activate

     If Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
          ActiveWorkbook.Close
       Else
          Application.Quit
     End If

    End If

End Sub
```

That is it for the code that goes inside the UserForm. And the code that is necessary to have the UserForm in VBA act as it's own application while allowing for Excel to operate normally at the same time as the UserForm.

To summarize what happens:

1. When the Workbook is launched the workbook is hidden, and if no other workbook is open the the Excel application is hidden.
2. The UserForm is initiated to allow for Excel to be used at the same time
3. When the spreadsheet is activated again excel is re-enabled and the application and un-hide the worksheet
4. When the user form is closed, the workbook is closed, and if there are no other workbooks the excel application is closed
5. If you set defaults or populate ComboBoxes put them in the "WorkBook" object code.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is having all the workbooks open, you can add a procedure to close all them all.

```
Sub Close_xls()
Dim objXl as Object
On error Go To GenerateXlErr
Set objXl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If not (ObjXl is Nothing) Then
    ObjXl.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ObjXl.Workbooks.Close
    ObjXl.Quit
    set ObjXl = Nothing
End If
Exit Sub
GenerateXLErr:
If Err.number = 432 or err.number = 429 THen
   Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

this is your workbook_open with the code rearranged

```
Private Sub WorkBook_Open()

    If Workbooks.Count = 1 Then Application.Visible = False

    Workbooks("MyBook.xlsm").Windows(1).Visible = False

    UserForm1.Show vbModeless

End Sub
```